# Error: a certificate chain processed,but terminated in a root error .Net Framework 4.7

Tags: c#, installation, wix, burn

I want to extract the .net 4.7 framework prerequisites with my main msı.

But when ı try to install .net installation give an error.

After ı try to install .net framework only.

.net framework installation gives an error

.net framework 4.7 a certificate chain processed but terminated in a root.

How to certificate it with Wix?

```
  <ExePackage
         InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx47FullLog].html&quot;"
          RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx47FullLog].html&quot;"
          UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx47FullLog].html&quot;"
          PerMachine="yes"
          DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx47WebDetectCondition)"

          InstallCondition="NetFrameWorkCheckbox = 1"
          Id="NetFx47Web"
          Vital="yes"
          Permanent="yes"
          Protocol="netfx4"
          DownloadUrl="$(var.NetFx47WebLink)"
          LogPathVariable="NetFx47FullLog"
          Compressed="yes"
     Name="!(wix.NetFx47WebPackageDirectory)NDP47-KB3186500-Web.exe"
    SourceFile=".\prerequisites\NNDP47-KB3186497-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"


         >
```

Answer (score 21):

I also met the same issue when installing .NET framework 4.7 on the PC with Win 7 sp1 system.

The solution with detailed steps is below can be seen in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60812129/6075331

[image: Step2]

Then the issue will hopefully be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Update***: `Recently down-voted. Please let others know what didn't work. I have not looked at this issue for a long time.`

---

***Heath Stewart's Blog***: I think you will find the explanation here: [A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority](https://web.archive.org/web/20140826095424/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2012/08/17/a-certificate-chain-could-not-be-built-to-a-trusted-root-authority.aspx). Essentially some components in Visual Studio 2012 were signed with a SHA256 hash certificate not installed on all Windows versions.

> ***Are you on a virtual?*** It might not be updated - ***running Windows Update might fix the whole problem?*** You need a **`root certificate update`**. I would try that before reading the information below. I would assume the problem would be fixed by now via Windows Update, but perhaps not?

---

You will find links in the above, linked blog. I will just inline a few of the links here (in case the blog disappears):

- [**KB2746268**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406075024/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2746268)
- [From MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/07d60dcb-f6c1-419c-99d4-e23fb4c3028c/a-certificate-chain-processed-but-terminated-in-a-root-certificate-which-is-not-trusted-by-the?forum=vssetup)
- [Configure Trusted Roots and Disallowed Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11))

And a general link just for reference: [.NET Framework deployment guide for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers).

Comment: Thank you but ı already ı added microsoft root certifacete and d3d compiler.dll.Now it works good.

Comment: Not sure I understand, you got it working some other way?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for .NET Framework 4.8 (and hopefully 4.7 as well):

Your PC may be missing a certificate: For my problem, I needed to import `MicRooCerAut2011.crt` to console root (windows + R, type "mmc", then press Enter).

[Here are step-by-step instructions](https://www.gagaltotal666.my.id/2020/04/mengatasi-net-framework-has-not-been.html) on how to do this (the text is in Indonesian, but the images should make sense anyway) and where to download the certificate file from.

Comment: A link to a non-English website is not very useful. It's preferable to simply add all the necessary details to the answer, and avoid the link entirely.